# Make local resources available when connected to Wireguard VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

BACKGROUND:
I have configured a Wireguard VPN server on my local (private) network. [Say private network: 192.168.1.0/24]
Wireguard clients have the same IP network 192.168.1.X

There are some non-Wireguard compatible devices (IP cameras, DVRs) in my network with static local IP addresses.

QUERY:
When I connect to the Wireguard server (from outside my local network) as a Wireguard client, I want to access those non-Wireguard compatible devices with their local static IP address. I have made sure that there won't b any IP conflicts.

Answer (score 10):

When you want to connect individual external hosts to a LAN via WireGuard, the three key things you need to do are:

1. Include the LAN's IP block (or at least the IP address of each individual LAN-side host you want to access) in the `AllowedIPs` setting of the WireGuard config on each *external* host
2. Set up packet forwarding on the LAN-side WireGuard host (eg `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`)
3. Set up packet masquerading (aka SNAT) on the LAN-side WireGuard host (usually done via `iptables` rules)

There's a complete example of this here:

https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2020/11/wireguard-point-to-site-config/

In that example, the LAN's subnet is `192.168.200.0/24`, so that's what `AllowedIPs` is set to in the WireGuard config of the external host (Endpoint A in the example):

```
AllowedIPs = 192.168.200.0/24
```

And in that example, packet forwarding and masquerading are accomplished by adding the following to the WireGuard config on the LAN-side WireGuard host (Host β in the example):

```
# IP forwarding
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# IP masquerading
PreUp = iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE
```

When the WireGuard interface `wg0` is up on the LAN-side WireGuard host, the external host can connect to any host on the LAN via its LAN address -- in the example, the external host (Endpoint A) can connect to a LAN host (Endpoint B) via Endpoint B's local address, `192.168.200.22`.

Comment: Wireguard claims to be a "simple" VPN protocol/solution, yet here we are ...

Comment: I think its simple for the context at this level. If you want to do more complicated things like making local networks available to the interface then you need to do a little configuration.

Comment: hi, i have the same question but for windows, is there anything i can do to achieve the same goal in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Having a LAN 192.168.50.1/24, among which there is a device acting as a VPN server (VPN 10.5.0.1/24), I can make an external client (10.5.0.4) to access a device on the original LAN (i.e., 192.168.50.185).

I achieve this by:

1. Enabling IP4 forward in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
2. Appending to `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` (field `[interface]`) the line:

   ```
   PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1; iptables -I INPUT 1 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT;iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
   ```

   Apply changes trough

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0
   ```
3. Configuring the client to forward traffic toward the desired host. i.e., on the client I have under the file `[Peer]`:

   ```
   AllowedIPs = 10.5.0.1/24;192.168.50.185/32
   ```

Hope this helps.